# change Display format of Date, day and month in Android DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I want to customize this display day, Date and Month format in EEEE d, MMMM Format.

[image: Date picker dialog]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: means how you want to customize..what is your expected output.

Comment: @GowthamanM I'm expecting **Friday 13, October** instead of *Fri, Oct 13*

Answer (score 1):

It's fully logical. You can try this

```
public static class EndDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        public AdvancedSearchFragment instant;
        public int dd = 0, mm, yyyy;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            if (dd == 0) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                yyyy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            }

            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yyyy, mm, dd);
            // Added all possible null conditions
            ((TextView)((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)((DatePicker)dpd.getDatePicker()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).setText("My Date");
            return dpd;
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
            instant.doSetEndTime(year, month + 1, day);
        }
    }
```

This below line will set the value of Fri, Oct 13

```
((TextView)((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)((DatePicker)dpd.getDatePicker()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).setText("My Date");
```

If you want to change the format of year 2017 then use below

```
((TextView)((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)((DatePicker)dpd.getDatePicker()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setText("My Year");
```

So in place of My Date you can use date format & set the date as you want.

I hope this will help!